# undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, registration

I have always used Devise for authentication. It's simple and customizable enough. Well today I started getting errors when signing up new users for NO reason. Didn't bundle update or nothing. Didn't accidentally delete something from a controller or config file. Very confused. I have googled this common error and have yet to find a solution. Have tried different versions of rails, devise, etc. and nothing seems to fix it. Reset my db too. Running out of ideas. Anyone else having the same problem?

About to switch to a different authentication gem or just build from scratch which is a pain in the A, but I don't know what else to do. It's 2019 and rails has been around for a while and this shouldn't be an issue. You can tell I'm frustrated lol.

### new_reviewer.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: registration_path(@user)) do |f| %>
<div class="registration-container">
  <h2>Sign up today!</h2>

  <div class="profile-pic">
    <%= f.label "Add a profile pic" %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div><br />
  <div class="user-roles">
    <%= f.select(:access_level, [['Reviewer', 'reviewer']]) %>
  </div><br />

  <div class="user-name">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div><br />

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

#users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def new_author
    @user = User.new
  end

  def new_reviewer
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.books.each do |b|
    @avg_rating = if b.reviews.blank?
    0
    else
      b.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
    end
  end
  end


  def profile
    @current_user = current_user
    @helpful = current_user.reviews.where(helpful: true)
    @unhelpful = current_user.reviews.where(unhelpful: true)
    @reviews = current_user.reviews
    unhelpful = @unhelpful.count
    total = @reviews.count
    subtotal = total - unhelpful
    @score = subtotal.to_f / total

  end

  def reviewer
    if params[:search]
      @reviewers_search = User.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
    else
      @reviewers_search = User.where(access_level: :reviewer).order('first_name ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
    end
  end

  def author
      if params[:search]
        @authors_search = User.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
        @author_rank = b.reviews.count 
      else
        @authors_search = User.where(access_level: :author).order('first_name ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end


  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:bio, :ranking, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :avatar, :access_level)
  end
end
```

## here's the stack trace from the terminal:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass):
    1: 
    2: <%= form_for(@user, url: registration_path(@user)) do |f| %>
    3: <div class="registration-container">
    4:   <h2>Sign up today!</h2>
    5: 
  
app/views/users/new_reviewer.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_users_new_reviewer_html_erb__2780381832095941109_47402928557320'
```

Comment: Why didnt you post the most important part - the full error with trace?

Comment: I apologize. I’ll edit the question soon. I asked it when I was beyond stressed because my bank account got compromised and my German car needs another repair probably. Hopefully it’ll shed some light. I know others have asked the same question on stackoverflow I just wasn’t able to benefit from the answers

Answer (score 0):

In my user.rb file I intialized an object which isn't necessary to do anymore and it was causing the error. Got rid of the initializer and boom. Back in business. Lesson learned.

```
def initialize(array)
  @array = array
end

def count_increases
  @array = self.reviews.size
  if @array += 1
    self.increment!(:ranking, 2)
  end
end
```

Comment: so, probably you had do add "super" at the end of initialize. Maybe this class had a parent which had its own initialize and used some parameters. and you did override the parents initialize without giving the same parameters. sometimes jsut "super" isnt enough, needs to pass additional *parameters and &block arguments if the parent uses them.

Comment: You’re correct. It had a parent class. Class User. And everything you said is most likely correct. Your knowledge is very advanced. I’m still very much a noob and adolescent in my rails/ruby knowledge however I am finally “getting there” in my development experience. Thanks for your input!